# flutter get data from api type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

this is my test code under
try to search but not working..
it will be something i missed..
Please help me to resolve this.

```
test('http test', () async {
        var uri = Uri.parse(
            'https:....posts.json');
        var response = await http.get(uri);
        expect(response.statusCode, 200);

        NewsInfo newsInfo = NewsInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(json.encode(response.body)));

        expect(newsInfo.id, "dc523f0ed25c");
      });
```

and this id json to dart

```
class NewsInfo {
  String id;
  int imageId;
  int imageThumbId;
  Metadata metadata;
  List<Paragraphs> paragraphs;
  Publication publication;
  String subtitle;
  String title;
  String url;

  NewsInfo(
      {this.id,
        this.imageId,
        this.imageThumbId,
        this.metadata,
        this.paragraphs,
        this.publication,
        this.subtitle,
        this.title,
        this.url});
  NewsInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    imageId = json['imageId'];
    imageThumbId = json['imageThumbId'];
    metadata = json['metadata'] != null
        ? new Metadata.fromJson(json['metadata'])
        : null;
    if (json['paragraphs'] != null) {
      paragraphs = new List<Paragraphs>();
      json['paragraphs'].forEach((v) {
        paragraphs.add(new Paragraphs.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    publication = json['publication'] != null
        ? new Publication.fromJson(json['publication'])
        : null;
    subtitle = json['subtitle'];
    title = json['title'];
    url = json['url'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
..
```

json looks like this under

```
[
  {
    "id": "dc523f0ed25c",
    "imageId": 2131165292,
    "imageThumbId": 2131165293,
    "metadata": {
      "author": {
        "name": "Pietro Maggi",
        "url": "https://medium.com/@pmaggi"
      },
      "date": "August 02",
      "readTimeMinutes": 1
    },
    "paragraphs": [
      {
        "markups": [],
        "text": "Working to make our Android application more modular, I ended up with a sample that included a set of on-demand features grouped inside a folder:",
        "type": "Text"
      },
```

and when i run the test it shows
test/widget_test.dart 23:47  main.
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
try to search but not working..
it will be something i missed..
Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json response looks like a list. Try

```
List<NewsInfo> news = json.decode(response.body).map((el) => NewsInfo.fromJson(el)).toList();
```